# Update text on ionic platform resume

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

i'm using ionic to develop an app, in the app i show a message to notify the user to enable location (if the user denied the permission).
I want to update this message when the user enables the location and switches back to the app.

**listing.page.ts file**

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.platform.resume.subscribe((e) => {
      this.diagnostic
      .isLocationAuthorized()
      .then((isEnabled) => {
       this.gotLocation = isEnabled;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
}
```

The message shows/hides if you close then run the app, however if you run the app then check the app info where you can allow/deny location then switch back to the app the message will not get updated unless i click on a tab or go to another page

I want to update the message as soon as it switches back to the app.

Comment: ios or android?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using capacitor. You can use the inbuilt plugin to check whether the app has permission for "Geolocation" or not.

```
const hasPermission = await Permissions.query({name:PermissionType.Geolocation});
```

And then you can check for these states

```
if(hasPermission.state =='prompt'){
  //user has not been prompted to allow location access
  //if you want to show a popup before prompting the user, do it here.. and after that initialize your geolocation plugin
}
else if(hasPermission.state =='denied'){
  //user has denied location access, prompt them to allow it
}
else if(hasPermission.state =='granted'){
  //user has granted location access
}
```

[Official Docs](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/permissions)